# Can Apex code tell if you are impersonating a user vs actually being logged in as that user?

Tags: apex

I would like my Apex code to know the difference between me being actually logged in as a particular Salesforce user, versus being logged in as an administrator and impersonating the user (because I clicked on his name and selected "Login").

I cannot find a documented way to do this, and knowing that this is the nature of impersonation, don't necessarily expect to find a documented API call that tells me this. But Salesforce definitely knows the difference, at least in the UI, and Logout while you're impersonating just stops the impersonation but leaves you logged in as the administrator again.

So, is there a way for Apex code to tell that it is actually an administrator impersonating a user?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm going to guess maybe you want to find out if an end user is actually performing certain actions or changes, vs. an admin logged in as them?  If not, I agree with @ReidCarlberg, why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is a good question:  Salesforce-UI clearly can distinguish between the two cases, but I'm not sure if it's accessible via SFDC.  **I suggest trying some test cases**:  create/edit records while logged in as another user, and see who the resulting **Record Owners** are, who the **Last Modified By** are, etc.  Do all the forensics you normally would do.

Comment: I would only want to know so I can log that the request was from impersonation.  I have a logging object where I record some permanent logging information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. As far as the code is concerned, the effective user is the user performing the action. Any records created by an administrator logged in as a user will have their createdby and lastmodifiedby audit fields set to that user, and userinfo.getuserid() will return the user being logged in as. *This is the same behavior as System.runAs() in test methods, with the exception that code can detect if it is being run in a test method.* There's nothing you can do, such as examining the session ID, etc, that would give you any clue at all, unless you know how to decrypt the session ID (hypothetically; presumably this is how the UI knows).

Answer (score 17):

Adding on to Daniel's post, there is a different class called SessionManagement that will return some, if not all of the AuthSession attributes for the current session.  This way, you can determine the type of session for the current session.

```
Map<String,String> currentSessionAttributes = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession();
String sessionType = currentSessionAttributes.get('SessionType');
//If sessionType == 'SubstituteUser', act on logged-in-as user.
```

Details on the SessionManagement class can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_SessionManagement.htm).

Answer (score 11):

It's not foolproof, but querying the [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) looks promising.

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to find the AuthSession records that correspond to the current SessionID - [How can I find the AuthSession that corresponds with the current Session Id?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/145309/102)

However, an impersonator will get AuthSession SessionType of **SubstituteUser**.

> **SubstituteUser**
>   A session created when one user logs in via another user. For example, if an administrator logs in as another user, a SubstituteUser session is created. [Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_session_types.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

They will also lack `LoginHistoryId`, `LoginType`, `LogoutUrl`, and `LoginGeoId` field values. The former is particularly interesting, as it shows they never really "logged in".

As a very rudimentary check from Apex:

```
List<AuthSession> authSession = [Select Id from AuthSession where UsersId = :UserInfo.getUserId() and SessionType = 'SubstituteUser'];
Boolean hasLoggedInUser = !authSession.isEmpty();
```

Of course, this won't handle cases where the actual user is also logged in at the same time. You could do some additional checks to see if there are other active sessions for the same `UsersId`.

---

Alternatively, on the client side you could check for the presence of a `RSID` cookie. If this exists then the current session is using the login as functionality.

Unfortunately you can't directly check for the presence of this cookie in Apex as it doesn't have the `apex_` prefix. Maybe write a new Apex accessible cookie client side if `RSID` is detected.

Comment: This is an interesting theory. I think I'll try it out.

Comment: how could we check impersonation in lightning component because document .cookie not access in component?

Answer (score 3):

The SessionType value retrieved from Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession() cannot be relied upon to determine if the user is a Substitute User or not.

This is because every user that is logged into the org will have multiple entries in the AuthSession table.  The SessionType value returned by getCurrentSession() reflects an entry in the AuthSession table where the value of IsCurrent = true.  In most cases, the SessionType value returned here will be 'UI', 'Aura' or 'Visualforce'.

However, the other entries for the session in the AuthSession table for this particular login still exist.

Retrieve the LoginHistoryId using Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().  All entries for this specific login in the AuthSession table will have the same value for LoginHistoryId.

Then query the AuthSession table using the LoginHistoryId value and determine whether or not there is at least one entry where SessionType = 'SubstituteUser'.  If there is at least one, then this particular session is an admin logged in as a user.