# How can I find the AuthSession that corresponds with the current Session Id?

Tags: api, oauth2, session

In my external application I have a Session ID (a.k.a Access_Token) and server URL. This may have been sourced from any number of locations. Such as:

- A Composite Apps query string URL on the iframe
- A Connected Apps signed request from a Canvas page
- One of several OAuth flows
- A direct Partner SOAP API login() call with the credentials

I'd like to figure out what I can and can't do with that session identifier I have. The [AuthSession.SessionType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) seems like a good candidate. Assuming I can at least query AuthSession with my current Session ID,  how can I determine which AuthSession corresponds to my current Session ID?

There is the `UsersId` field, but that could have multiple matches for any single user.

---

Real world scenario I was trying to solve.

There is some ancient (cira 2008) code that uses `/servlet/servlet.ReportList` to get the list of available Reports in an org for the current session user. This app had historically used a Composite App iframe to get the session Id and has been working pretty reliably to date. It fell into the ain't broke don't fix it pile rather than getting upgraded to the newer Reporting API.

Then very recently it started failing with the response `<?xml version="1.0"?><result>Invalid session.</result>`. This was very odd, as the problem session Id could be used for any number of other API calls, just not to this servlet.

It eventually dawned on me that the app had very recently been changed to use a Canvas App which didn't have the OAuth web or full scopes. Turns out that without those it wasn't possible to consume that servlet.

But I had no way of telling if the Session ID I was looking at had the required Session Type and no way to reconcile it with the AuthSession records.

Comment: I think you could try `ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC`, but I'm not sure if that'd be productive.

Comment: Can add "NumSecondsValid" and check session expired or not too.

Comment: @Reshma An interesting idea, but I'm not sure how I can check it with only the Session ID and an API call without resetting the value from the call where I'm checking the value.

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess if I was quick enough after establishing the session I could be reasonable certain that the most recent one was mine. I'll expand the question with the scenario I was trying to solve.

Comment: I am surprised SalesForce have not given a way to query the AuthSession object using a `UserInfo.getSessionId()`

Answer (score 3):

This is now partially possible using [`AuthSession.IsCurrent`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm):

> If true, the session is a member of the user’s current session family.

This was introduced in Summer'16 (v37.0).

Comment: I have a similar problem. I want to use this but I can't find a definition for 'current session family' ? What does that really mean ?