# Class/Trigger that will check if the one editing a record/making actions is a System Admin (logged in as different User)

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there an object or a namespace or technique using Apex to check if the User doing the changes (create, edit, etc) is a System Admin (logged in as different User)?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I've linked a relevant answer for you. If you feel this answer isn't useful, please [edit] your post to include additional information, and we can re-open your question for you.

Comment: Actually, I don't have an easy way to verify this, but you might look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/222302/2984) as well, it may serve your needs.