# How can I tell where a user logged in to an Experience Site?

Tags: apex, trigger, user, experience-cloud, userinfo

I have an experience site where Customer Community Users can sign up, log in, and add items to their cart for purchase. Is it possible to recognize someone who logged in to this Experience Site as a specific user? The use case of this would be for Customer Service users who help out Customers with their orders. If the Customer Service user is logged into the experience site as a Customer to help them modify/complete their order, I would want to be able to track that. The Customer Service user logs into the experience site through a Contact record like so:

[image]

I have a before insert/update trigger for when an item is added/updated in the cart. I'm looking to be able to recognize whether it was actually the Customer who has made changes to their cart or the Customer Service user. This is so that I can have the Last Modified By field more accurately reflect who is updating the Cart and Line Item records.

Currently I have attempted with `UserInfo.getUserType()` to find out who's making changes, but when I 'Log in to Experience as User' through the Org, it does not return my System Admin User information. Instead it returns the Customer Community User's information.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and describe _how_ "the Customer Service user [is] logged into the experience site as a Customer". Include code (if custom).

Comment: @identigral I have no real code yet. I have updated question with a screen shot of how the Customer Service user would log in.

Comment: This Q&A while old still applies: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22741/can-apex-code-tell-if-you-are-impersonating-a-user-vs-actually-being-logged-in-a

Comment: Look at the second answer in the above for details.